# How to verify that static method was invoked with exact arguments?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have following method to test:

```
public static Map<String, CrxEntity> getCrxEntitiesByMixin(Session readSession, String rootPath, SupportedLocale locale, String mixin, String idPropertyName, Set<String> propertyNamesToStore) throws RepositoryException {
        return getCrxEntitiesByMixin(readSession, rootPath, locale, mixin, idPropertyName, propertyNamesToStore, null, false);
    }
```

Following method invoke another public method thus I should to test only that arguments passed properly.

I have wrote following code:

```
    @Test
    public void getCrxEntitiesByMixinTest() throws RepositoryException {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(StaticUtils.class);

        when(StaticUtils.getCrxEntitiesByMixin(any(Session.class),anyString(),any(SupportedLocale.class),anyString(),anyString(),anySet(),anyList(),anyBoolean())).thenReturn(null);

        StaticUtils.getCrxEntitiesByMixin(sessionMock, "rootPath", SupportedLocale.EN, "mixin", "idPropName", Sets.<String>newHashSet());

        verify(StaticUtils.getCrxEntitiesByMixin(eq(sessionMock), eq("rootPath"), eq(SupportedLocale.EN), eq("mixin"), eq("idPropName"), eq(Sets.<String>newHashSet()), eq(Lists.<String>newArrayList()), eq(false)));
    }
```

I see following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NullInsteadOfMockException: 
Argument passed to verify() should be a mock but is null!
Examples of correct verifications:
    verify(mock).someMethod();
    verify(mock, times(10)).someMethod();
    verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).someMethod();
Also, if you use @Mock annotation don't miss initMocks()
```

How to resolve my problem?

Comment: I think the error is clear enough: you're passing null whilst verify() is expecting a mock. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you advise how to rewrite code? I think that idea is clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer.
Powermockito has very confusing syntax for this:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
StaticUtils.getCrxEntitiesByMixin(eq(sessionMock), eq("rootPath"), eq(SupportedLocale.EN), eq("mixin"), eq("idPropName"), eq(Sets.<String>newHashSet()), eq((List<String>)null), eq(false));
```

full example:
https://gist.github.com/ThoMo/3916072